# Java | Cypher project decryption

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

Came across a sort of bug while doing an assignment. I isolated the problem to one for loop block of code here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cipherArray.length; i++) {
    int tempSum = 26 + cipherArray[i] - longkeyArray[i];
    decrypArray[i] = tempSum % 26;  
}
```

the `cipherArray` variable is an array of `int`s that coincide to a letter
`0 = a, 1 = b` ...

`cipherArray` is coded, using the `longkeyArray` variable.

the `longkeyArray` variable is an array of `int`s which also coincide to a letter in the same way.

The for loop is supposed to decrypt the `cipherArray` by subtracting the value of the key from each space in the Array, adding 26, and then doing modulo 26
eg. `(26 + 11 - 1) % 26 = 12`

I then end up with a decoded array of integers.

the PROBLEM comes when I run it, everything works fine except for the first value in `decrypArray`, which always turns out to be `z`.

I have tried it with multiple keys and encoded messages, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: We'll need you to post the minimal amount of code that can be successfully executed so we can try to solve your problem.

Comment: `(26 + 11 - 1) % 26` is **not** 12, the result is **10**.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That was probably just a typo.

Comment: If the first character is always `z` but the other characters are fine, then there is something wrong in the encryption, since your decryption doesn't do anything special/different for the first character.

Comment: @JacobG. A typo in the expression, a type in the code that was posted, a misunderstand from the OP somehow. All are possible. Let the OP address it.

Comment: Is the `z` maybe an artifact from *how you print the result*? Please show us the code where you use the method you've provided *including how you print the result*!